# How to fetch FULL cookie with cURL?

Tags: curl, cookies, session-cookies, setcookie

I'm recently working on an API. It's an API running at localhost. It requires login sessions to use its functions. As the API is running on a CentOS server without a GUI, so I need to save the cookie from a session and use the saved cookie to access to functions with cURL.

Here are some cookie generating and logging on trials with cURL.

```
curl --cookie-jar cookie_with_--cookie-jar_option.txt 'localhost:3000/login/cellphone?phone=[number]&password=[password]' //saving cookie with --cookie-jar option

curl --dump-header cookie_with_--dump-header_option.txt 'localhost:3000/login/cellphone?phone=[number]&password=[password]' //saving cookie with --dump-header option
```

And some API-function tests with the generated cookie file.

```
curl --cookie cookie_with_--cookie-jar_option.txt 'localhost:3000/daily_signin' //using cookie generated with --cookie-jar option

curl --cookie cookie_with_--dump-header_option.txt 'localhost:3000/daily_signin' //using cookie generated with --dump-header option
```

But all returned "not logged in" error. It's all fine when I access the API with a browser.

Later I looked into the cookie file generated by both options. Below are samples.

Screenshot of the cookie generated by --dump-header
[image: A screenshot of the cookie generated by --dump-header]

Screenshot of the cookie generated by --cookie-jar
[image: A screenshot of the cookie generated by --cookie-jar]

These cookies are really confusing. Which one is the full cookie? Which one is the original cookie returned from the server? If they are all not the right one, what command or option should I use to fetch a full cookie?

Comment: Your question command lines contain odd underscores. Are they there for a reason or did your command line actually have them there like that?

Comment: @DanielStenberg it's just a part of the filename.

Comment: Ah sorry, I was just confused by the option names embedded in the file names. You want the `--cookie-jar` version to store the correct and full cookie information.

Answer (score 0):

The dump header is returning the HTTP request header.  You need to get the HTTP response header to see the set cookies.

The cookie jar appears to be correct.  That is, if the MUSIC_U and _csrf were not set at that time.